# How to get method's return type in OkHttp Interceptor?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

Via `okhttp3.Request#tag(Invocation::class.java)`, we can get `methodName`, `annotations` etc. Is there any way to get the method's return type using `Invocation` class.

I've tried

- `request.tag(Invocation::class.java)!!.method().returnType`
- `request.tag(Invocation::class.java)!!.method().genericReturnType`

but both of them simply return `class java.lang.Object`, even it's a `List`.

## Expected Output

```kotlin
@GET("products")
suspend fun getProducts(): List<Product>  // I need to get at least `List` as a String for this method

@GET("product")
suspend fun getProduct(): Product // I need to get at least `Object` as a String for this method
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a suspend function so the return type of the java.lang reflect.Method is not the return type you declared. Look a the decompiled bytecode and you'll see the Java method and where the declared return type ends up in the signature.

Comment: Okay, I've seen the return type in the signature field string. Now, how can I get the return type in code, it's a private field? https://i.imgur.com/AFKDM45.png @Jesse

Comment: Use reflection on the reflection class Method? :-|